# Partition detected as in use even after successful unmount?

Tags: mount, block-device

I'm having a USB disk which I unmount and want to perform some actions on it (i.e. do a file system check). Even though the disk was unmounted the system complains that it's still in used. The OS in question is `Ubuntu 20.04.3`.

```
# Unmount the disk and all partitions
$ sudo umount /dev/sdb*
$ e2fsck -f /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

The partition nor the disk are listed in the output of `mount`

```
$ mount | grep 90a5ff5d
$ mount | grep sdb
```

There isn't an obvious process blocking the file

```
$ sudo lsof | grep /dev/sdb

# Suggestion was to check the mountpoint also.
# Full path /media/user/90a5ff5d-c3ef-4fbc-8efa-611ae498fca4
$ sudo lsof | grep 90a5ff5d
```

I have also tried debugging with `strace`, but only got the following which seems relevant:

```
$ strace e2fsck -f /dev/sdb1
...
...
stat("/dev/sdb1", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0777, st_rdev=makedev(0x8, 0x11), ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/sdb1", O_RDONLY|O_EXCL) = -1 EBUSY (Device or resource busy)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
...
...
```

Are there any other steps I can take to release the device or debug the issue?

Comment: Check the mountpoint of `dev/sdb1` and search with `lsof` this mountpoint

Comment: Also check the output of `mount` (no arguments). Ah, and please mention your OS you never know when that might make a difference.

Comment: @terdon What to check in `mount` (no arguments)?

Comment: Whether it lists any mounted partitions from `/dev/sdb`. Try `mount | grep sdb` for example. Also check the UUID of your `sdb` partitions (see the output of `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`) and see if any of those UUIDs are listed in the output of `mount`.

Comment: In the above commands, what is your `pwd`?

Comment: Are you by any mean running a Docker Daemon where one of the container has a volume mapped on that file system?
If so, by stopping the container, I fixed the same problem that I also had.
Cheers!

Comment: good call @terdon, uuid was found.  listed, and its output is only ../../sdj1.  and i already verified that was unmounted.  still e2fsck has issues saying its in use.

Also note check that your not `cd`'d into that dir anywhere also.  im not..